# Pretérito pluscuamperfecto y condicional implica que algo no haya sucedido

Tags: pretérito, condicional

Doy contexto para entender la situación:
Hay una persona que solía ser mi amiga y ahora estamos peleados. Ayer nos cruzamos casi de frente en la calle y ella no me miró ni me dirigió la palabra. Pueden haber sucedido dos casos: o no me vio, o me vio y me ignoró.

Contándole la situación a un amigo, él me quiso explicar que, debido a la relación que yo tengo con dicha persona, si me hubiera visto probablemente me habría ignorado. Sin embargo, al decir la frase "Si ella te hubiera visto te habría ignorado", nos sonó a que se estaba implicando el hecho de que ella no me vio; y nos quedamos debatiendo si es así o no.

Entonces, aquí viene la pregunta. Al usar pretérito pluscuamperfecto seguido de un condicional, se está obligatoriamente implicando que algo sucedió de la manera opuesta?

Otro ejemplo (perdón, no se me ocurrió algo poco intrincado):

> "No sé quién ganó, y la sala de festejos está vacía. Igualmente, si hubiera ganado nuestro equipo ya habría terminado el festejo." (No sé ni quién ganó ni si ocurrió un festejo, pero al decir eso suena a que implico que el equipo no ganó.)

No sé si explicarlo en términos de lógica proposicional sirve de algo pero en mi cabeza ayuda a entender mi pregunta, así que lo agrego igual. Yendo a la lógica, sería:

```
A o B.
A entonces C, C entonces D.
B entonces D.
Decir "Si hubiera ocurrido A entonces C" implica no A.
Ergo B.
```

Answer (score 1):

No, a la pregunta. El uso del pretérito pluscuamperfecto del subjuntivo no significa que algo sucedió de la manera opuesta. Hay una naturaleza contrafactual del enunciado, una incerteza acerca de si podría o no haber sucedido.

> si ella te hubiera visto, (probablemente/igualmente/seguramente) te habria ignorado

Esto (al no saberse si el destinatario de la frase fue visto por la aludida tercera) es contrafáctico: no sabemos si sucedió, porque no hay y manera de constatarlo, por lo tanto, su derivación condicional habita un plano de especulación teórica imaginaria. Este uso del pluscuamperfecto permite  considerar una  situación hipotética pasada, y enunciar una consecuencia  (esperable) condicionada a aquella.

La frase alude a algo posible de haber sucedido, y una consecuencia imaginada bajo la interpretación subjetiva de quien  construye el argumento (a la luz del conocimiento suyo de un contexto previo, la personalidad de ella y el estado de la relacion con su interlocutor, etc).

El  modo subjuntivo y  el tiempo pluscuamperfecto es usable tampién para especular con una consecuencia posible condicionada a otro hecho probable; un modo de conjeturar sobre posibilidades de cuestiones ligables en una relación de causa y efecto

> `en caso de haber sido cierto A en vez de B, —probablemente— habría sucedido la situación C`)

Se alude por tanto a una consecuencia (no segura pero posible o esperable) bajo una condición postulada (de manera teórica) como cierta

Answer (score 0):

> Hay una persona que solía ser mi amiga y ahora **estamos peleados**.

> **Contándole la situación a un amigo, él me quiso explicar** que, debido a la relación que yo tengo con dicha persona

> ...si me hubiera visto **probablemente** me habría ignorado.

> al decir la frase "Si ella te **hubiera** visto te **habría** ignorado", nos sonó a que **se estaba implicando el hecho de que ella no me vio**;

La implicación es porque él sabe que están peleadas a partir de tu relato, al decir esa frase condicional sin ese conocimiento puede bien significar tanto que te haya visto como que no.

Es una hipótesis que alude un evento pasado pero para cual no se tiene certeza porque no sabemos si la involucrada te vio o no, no tenemos su versión del hecho o de si comparte el distanciamiento, sólo tenemos la apreciación personal tuya y de tu amigo poniéndose en el caso de lo que ella hubiera hecho si te hubiera visto.

Al tener sólo una suposición en el presente de un hecho acaecido en tu pasado o tu/su percepción subjetiva de lo que lógica o normalmente significaría o habría sucedido a partir de lo que le contaste o lo que asumiste en la línea de tiempo, la apódosis no te indica "no me/te vio".

> "No sé quién ganó, y **la sala de festejos está vacía**. Igualmente, **si hubiera** ganado nuestro equipo ya **habría** terminado el festejo." (No sé ni quién ganó ni si ocurrió un festejo, pero al decir eso suena a que implico que el equipo no ganó.)

En el segundo ejemplo sabe que la sala de festejos está vacía, por eso se carga la balanza hacia un lado, pero aún así puede que haya habido un festejo que terminó pronto porque tal o cual equipo es el local y tú al no haber llegado al lugar a la misma hora de ocurridos los eventos no tienes la certeza.

La frase "si hubiera ganado nuestro equipo ya habría terminado el festejo" por sí sola no dice que el equipo no ganó o si en realidad ocurrió o no un festejo, es sólo lo que se supone o lo que lógicamente sucedería dados los acontecimientos, que no son de hecho reveladores.

Te recomiendo leer esto:
[El valor del tiempo en las expresiones contrafactuales*](https://www.scielo.cl/scielo.php?script=sci_arttext&pid=S0716-58112015000200016)

En un lógico‐semántico entre  prótasis y apódosis:

- "Si ella te hubiera visto(no te vio) te habría ignorado(no te ignoro)"

Si hubiera ocurrido el evento de verte hubiera propiciado el de ignorarte(hipotéticamente) pero si por el contrario no lo hizo imposible(el que te ignorara)

- "Si ella te hubiera visto(si te vio) te habría ignorado(si te ignoro)"
- "Si ella te hubiera visto(no te vio pero UDs creen que sí) te habría ignorado(si te ignoro)"
- "Si ella te hubiera visto(si te vio) te habría ignorado(no te ignoró pero UDs creen que sí)"
- Si hubiera ganado nuestro equipo(no ganó) ya habría terminado el festejo(no terminó el festejó)
- Si hubiera ganado nuestro equipo(si ganó) ya habría terminado el festejo(sí terminó el festejó)

En negación la no terminación del festejo indicaría que no ganó, pero como dije antes depende de la línea de acontecimientos y quien y en que momento lo dice.

Comment: "vio" es un monosílabo y, al no existir necesidad de diferenciarse de un homónimo (en cuyo caso se debería utilizar el acento diacrítico), no lleva tilde. Lo mismo ocurre con *fue, fui, dio*.

Comment: Las normas ortográficas están para cumplirse. Este es un foro que muchos usan para aprender. No es correcto difundir una ortografía incorrecta. Si usas "vió", también deberías usar *ví, tí, dí*, todas incorrectas.

Comment: @Gustavson Me parece irrelevante en relación a la pregunta.

Comment: Nunca la ortografía es irrelevante. Si fuera así, ¿escribirías "ubiera" sin "h" y deberíamos pasarlo por alto?

Comment: @Gustavson En todos escribí vio, o en su mayoría, o lo edité cuando posteabas. Más encima el buscador no diferencia entre "vio" y "vió", así que no la encuentro. Lo mismo que con "mí"/"mi"

Comment: O ya me lo habías editado.

Answer (score 0):

Al usar pretérito pluscuamperfecto seguido de un condicional, se está obligatoriamente implicando que algo sucedió de la manera opuesta?

---

En líneas generales el subjuntivo sirve para expresar deseos, opiniones, ambigüedades, aspectos subjetivos, hipotéticos, inciertos, también enuncia duda, probabilidad, muchas veces relacionado con las emociones y sensaciones del que habla.

---

En mi opinión

- La **primera oración** "**Si ella te hubiera visto te habría ignorado**". En esta frase el hecho de que te hubiera visto no implica que obligatoriamente  algo tenga que suceder de la manera opuesta, la presencia del pretérito pluscuamperfecto de subjuntivo de manera contraria se da con "acciones conocidas", es decir, acciones acabadas del pasado, el que habla no señala ninguna hipótesis sobre esas acciones, por ejemplo;
- Si hubiera estudiado chino ... (por tanto (PT.) el interlocutor entiende que no estudiaste chino)
- Si hubiera ido a Nueva York... (PT. el interlocutor entiende perfectamente que no fuiste a Nueva York)
- Si hubiera caminado 5 km más... (PT. el interlocutor entiende perfectamente que no caminaste 5 km más)

---

Este caso, como en el de la segunda oración, "*no sé quién ganó, y la sala de festejos está vacía. Igualmente, si hubiera ganado nuestro equipo...*", son aquellos en que la información puede ser desconocida o incompleta.

Ejemplo

"Si hubiera comido mi profesor ya habría llegado a clase"

En estos casos la persona que habla asume o da por consabido, que "el profesor no ha comido” porque aún no se encuentra en clase, pero realmente no hay certeza de que esa sea la razón o la única razón por la que el profesor no haya llegado todavía al aula, por tanto la información sobre el profesor es desconocida, aunque la clase haya comenzado hace un par de horas o el profesor no acuda en varios días.

- La **segunda oración** es igual que la anterior, "**si hubiera ganado nuestro equipo ya habría terminado el festejo**" realmente no suena a que el equipo hubiera perdido, **la información que recibimos sobre la probabilidad de nuestro equipo es desconocida**, "**si hubiera ganado nuestro equipo ya habría "pasado" el festejo**", la carga de la oración más bien la tiene el "festejo" y la hora o tiempo al que se traslada la acción supuesta de su celebración y en el ahora, nuestro presente, cuando la acción ya ha finalizado. **La información que recibimos sobre la probabilidad del "festejo" si es conocida** pues se enmarca dentro de un plazo. Es como decir, "**Si hubiera actuado nuestro cantante favorito ya habría terminado el festejo o actuación**". Por tanto, en conclusión el festejo ya termino, independientemente de que actuara o no nuestro cantante favorito y sin nosotros aún saberlo, pues la información y el plazo que recibimos sobre el "festejo" si es conocida, aunque desconocida sea aún la información sobre la actuación del cantante.

El que ha perdido es uno mismo, que ya no puede asistir a la actuación del cantante favorito o a la celebración o no celebración del festejo de nuestro equipo, pues de todas formas el plazo temporal en que se desarrollaba ya expiro, pero en modo alguno de ello se puede extraer la conclusión de que el cantante no actuara o que el equipo tuviera que perder.

En estos casos mejor construir la oración con dos pretéritos pluscuamperfectos de subjuntivo que con el condicional compuesto, que resulta más claro en ciertos momentos. "**Si ella te hubiera visto te hubiera "o hubiese" ignorado**" "**Si hubiera ganado nuestro equipo ya "hubiera" terminado el festejo**".

En aquellas oraciones que la información de probabilidad no es completa, ante la duda de esta eventualidad y para distinguirlas de las "acciones conocidas", se puede utilizar la partícula "caso".

Ejem. "En el caso de que me hubiera saludado...", "En el caso de que hubiera ganado nuestro equipo...", realmente no lo sabemos o no conocemos aún la información de probabilidad correspondiente.
Si utilizamos la partícula con "acciones conocidas" el resultado no varia y conocemos de forma clara su sentido de probabilidad. En el caso de que hubiera ido a Nueva York..." (No fui a Nueva York), "En el caso de que hubiera comido paella..". (No comí paella).

P.D. Normalmente y de forma casi general, con sus excepciones, la combinación de si + pretérito pluscuamperfecto de subjuntivo + pretérito pluscuamperfecto de subjuntivo o condicional compuesto  es utilizada para lamentar una situación pasada, recriminar algo o hacer algún reproche.

Answer (score -1):

La frase:
"Si ella te hubiera visto, te habría ignorado" implica que no te vio. Esta es la opinion de tu amigo que no imagina que una buena amiga pudiera no reconocerte.

Y esta:
"No sé quién ganó, y la sala de festejos está vacía. Igualmente, si hubiera ganado nuestro equipo, ya habría terminado el festejo." implica que el festejo por tu equipo ya hubiera terminado a la hora que es, por ejemplo.

**Las oraciones condicionales son todas al respecto de situaciones que no se produjeron.** Por eso son condicional. Dependen de una condición.

> Las oraciones condicionales se componen de una oración principal y de
> una oración subordinada, donde la subordinada manifiesta **la condición
> que ha de cumplirse para que se ocurra lo que enuncia la oración
> principal**. La oración subordinada va encabezada por la conjunción si.

[oraciones condicionales](https://espanol.lingolia.com/es/gramatica/estructura-de-la-oracion/oraciones-condicionales)

Y finalmente:

"Si hubiera ocurrido A, entonces C" no habría pasado". es lo correcto.

La frase no termina en/con C. Termina con **habría C**.

Comment: Que una oración sea condicional no tiene nada que ver con que la condición se cumpla o no. ‘Si se calienta el agua a 100 grados, entonces hierve’. Yo puedo hacer hervir el agua y en ese caso estaría cumpliendo la condición. Un condicional solamente expresa qué es lo que ocurre (consecuente) cuando se cumple la condición (antecedente). No dice nada sobre valores de verdad. Esto debería estar explicado en cualquier libro de lógica básica

Comment: La estructura es: ‘Si (hubiera ocurrido) A entonces B’, pero no ‘A es falso’ como bien escribís en tu respuesta. O bien puedo no tener información (lo que suele ocurrir) o bien puede que ocurra B y en ese caso no voy a poder saber si se dio A